# Taylor Series of $\sin 2x$ finding $f^{(n)} (a)$ where $a = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

ok so i get;

f (x) = sin 2x

f ' = 2cos 2x

f '' = -4sin 2x

f ''' = -8cos 2x

f '''' = 16sin 2x

f ''''' = 32cos 2x

f (0) = 0

f '(0) = 2

f ''(0) = 0

f '''(0) = -8

f ''''(0) = 0

f '''''(0) = 32

now how do i find the general formula for $f^{(n)} (a)$  and what is the difference with n and k?

Comment: Who said anything about $k$?

Comment: Compare what happens to $f^n(0)$ when n is odd and when n is even. Then compare n with the powers of 2 obtained by $f^n(0)$ when n is odd.

Comment: Also what happens to the sign when n=4k-1 and n=4k+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f^{(n)}x=\begin{cases}(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}\,\;2^n\sin 2x&\;,\;\;n=0,2\pmod 4\\{}\\(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}2^n\cos 2x&\;,\;\;n=1,3\pmod 4\end{cases}$$

And I've no idea what you mean by "the difference with n and k"

Comment: in my textbook, for ex. sometimes they set n = 2k, but dont explain what k is..

Comment: like for taylor series of sin x

Comment: The notation $\,n=2k\,$ very probably means that $\,n\,$ runs  on the (or is an) even (positive, apparently) integers, like with the MacClaurin series for $$\cos x=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think what your textbook is saying is this:
$$f^{(n)}(0)=\begin{cases}(-1)*2^n\,\;&\;,\;\;n=4k+3\\{}\\2^n&\;,\;\;n=4k+1\\{}\\0&\;,\;\;n=2k\ \end{cases}$$
Where k=0,1,2,...

Comment: ok theyre ans is ${(-1)^k * 2 ^ {(2k+1)} * x ^{(2k+1)} }/ (2k+1)! $....so they set n = 2k +1 ...my bad i dont know how to make it look nice in math format on here